# How to check if a single column Datatable Contains a some String if it has no Primary key?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq, datatable, contains

is this possible without looping and checking every value? is there something simple like using contains in a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Linq-To-DataSet` and [`Enumerable.Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
Dim containsValue = table.AsEnumerable()
                         .Any(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Column") = "Foo")
```

or in query syntax:

```
Dim containsValue = (From r In table
                     Where r.Field(Of String)("Column") = "Foo").Any()
```

You need to add `Imports System.Linq`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method and specify a filter.